# Can I get ANSI-code-based colored output for tasks in VS Code's Output Panel?

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I've been following [this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-typescript-workflow-with-gulp) from Dan Wahlin to get a gulp task up and running. Now I wanted to execute it from VS Code with Ctrl+Shift+B so I configured this task runner:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [
    "--no-color"
],
"tasks": [{"taskName":"default","isBuildCommand": true,"isWatching": true,"showOutput": "silent"}]
```

}

The "--no-color" argument is default in the tasks.json that is automatically created by VSCode. If I remove it, the output from gulp is still not showing colors. I want my lint errors to show up in red text.

Is it possible to get colored output from gulp within the VSCode output window?

Answer (score 18):

Currently not, but we have a plan item to support colored output for the future.

You can follow it up [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/243).

Comment: Thanks for the verification. Keep up the good work with this great editor!

Comment: signed, this would be awesome!

Comment: I would very much like to have this also!

Comment: Now 5 years later, you still have that plan, but just closed that thread w/o providing a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon Output Colorizer from IBM. It works perfectly! It is available on the VS Code marketplace at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer

Alternatively you can just look for *Output Colorizer* from the extension palette in VS Code.

Comment: Perfectly? It's trying to speculate on the nature of user output and it's is printing just nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your tasks.json:

"_runner": "terminal",

That will redirect the output to the internal terminal, and will show colors properly.

Comment: Where does this "_runner" come from? Can one use it in `launch.json`?